# Show convergence of measurable functions is not induced by convergence of topology

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let X be the set of all measurable functions from $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. On this set we can define pointwise convergence up to a $\mu$ null set.

Now I want to show that there is **no** topology, where the definition of convergence in said topology is equivalent to the pointwise convergence up to a $\mu$ null set.

I want to do this by constructing a sequence of measurable functions, where every subsequence converges to the same function, but the original sequence does not converge to the same function or not at all ( all up to a $\mu$ null set of course ). If I can construct such an example, this would prove that no such topology can exist, because topological convergence has to satisfy this property.

But I'm having trouble coming up with an example and **am looking for hints on how to construct such a sequence of functions!**